# Pexpect Multi-Threading Idle State

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, pexpect

We have ~15,000 nodes to log into and pull data from via Pexpect.  To speed this up, I am doing multiprocessing - splitting the load equally between 12 cores.  That works great, but this is still over 1000 nodes per core - processed one at a time.

The CPU utilization of each core as it does this processing is roughly 2%.  And that sort of makes sense, as most of the time is just waiting for to see the Pexpect expect value as the node streams output.  To try and take advantage of this and speed things up further, I want to implement multi-threading within the multi-processing on each core.

To attempt avoid any issues with shared variables, I put all data needed to log into a node in a dictionary (one key in dictionary per node), and then slice the dictionary, with each thread receiving a unique slice.  Then after the threads are done, I combine the dictionary slices back together.

However, I am still seeing one thread *completely* finish before moving to the next.

I am wondering what constitutes an idle state such that a core can be moved to work on another thread?  Does the fact that it is always looking for the Pexpect expect value mean it is never idle?

Also, as I use the same target function for each thread.  I am not sure if perhaps that target function being the same for each thread (same vars local to that function) is influencing this?

My multi-threading code is below, for reference.

Thanks for any insight!

```
import threading
import <lots of other stuff>

class ThreadClass(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, outputs_dict_split):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__()
        self.outputs_dict_split = outputs_dict_split
    def run(self):
        outputs_dict_split = get_output(self.outputs_dict_split)
        return outputs_dict_split

def get_output(outputs_dict):
    ### PEXPECT STUFF TO LOGIN AND RUN COMMANDS ####
    ### WRITE DEVICE'S OUTPUTS TO DEVICE'S OUTPUTS_DICT RESULTS SUB-KEY ###

def backbone(outputs_dict):
    filterbykey = lambda keys: {x: outputs_dict[x] for x in keys}
    num_threads = 2
    device_split = np.array_split(list(outputs_dict.keys()), num_threads)

    outputs_dict_split_list = []
    split_list1 = list(device_split[0])
    split_list2 = list(device_split[1])
    outputs_dict_split1 = filterbykey(split_list1)
    outputs_dict_split2 = filterbykey(split_list2)
    t1 = ThreadClass(outputs_dict_split1)
    t2 = ThreadClass(outputs_dict_split2)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    outputs_dict_split1 = t1.outputs_dict_split
    outputs_dict_split2 = t2.outputs_dict_split
    outputs_dict_split_list.append(outputs_dict_split1)
    outputs_dict_split_list.append(outputs_dict_split2)
    outputs_dict = ChainMap(*outputs_dict_split_list)

    ### Downstream Processing ###
```

Comment: Thank you.  This actually worked - with processing time reduced significantly - but only when I increased number of devices to more than the two I was using for a test.  I am not exactly sure the reason for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually worked.  However, I had to scale the number of devices being processed in order to see substantial improvements in overall processing time.